# Can Bards learn Oath of the Open Sea Spells via Magical Secrets? If so, does it require the GM's discretion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, paladin, bard

The **Oath of the Open Sea Spells** section of *Tal’dorei Campaign Setting: Reborn* says:

> Paladins of the Oath of the Open Sea automatically gain two new spells through their Oath Spells feature. These spells can also be learned by druids, rangers, and sorcerers of the appropriate level, at the GM's discretion.

The *Player's Handbook*, Ch. 3 (Bard), says:

> **Magical Secrets**
>
> By 10th level, you have plundered magical knowledge from a wide spectrum of disciplines. Choose two spells from any classes, including this one. A spell you choose must be of a level you can cast, as shown on the Bard table, or a cantrip.
>
> The chosen spells count as bard spells for you and are included in the number in the Spells Known column of the Bard table.

Can a Bard use the Magical Secrets feature to learn one or both of the two new Sea spells because Magical Secrets is more specific, or is the "can also be learned by" line more specefic and thus prevents the Bard from learning them? Also, does the "at the GM's discretion" portion of the Tal'dorei rules apply here (aside from the fact that the entire game is at the GM's discretion)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Maybe

If the DM allows druids, rangers and sorcerers to learn these spells, they are effectively added to the spell list of those classes similar to the"Additional [class] Spells" optional rules in TCE. That would make these spells available to bards through magical secrets.

If the spells are not allowed for druids, rangers and sorcerers, it's not clear whether they would qualify as "spells from any class". They are not on any class' spell list, yet they are gained from being a paladin. That situation is not covered by the rules, as far as I know, and would be completely up to the DM.